# Django - "Page not found (404)" after trying to login (Shared Hosting)

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, admin, django-urls

I installed Django in my server, after that i was able to see the "IT WORKED" page and the "Django administration" page (www.mydomain.com/admin).

I sync my Database (No problem with that), I collected my static files as well

The problem comes when I try to login into the administration page,

[image: As you can see here, I get my admin login interface with all the styles]

After I try to login with or without the correct username or password I get:

[image]

I checked my urls.py and didn't find anything out of the ordinary:

project/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from app_belldent import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from sitio_belldent import settings

admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.inicio, name="inicio"),
    url(r'^servicios/$', views.servicios, name="servicios"),
    url(r'^portafolio/$', views.portafolio, name="portafolio"),
    url(r'^contactenos/$', views.contact, name="contactenos"),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

app/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.inicio),
    url(r'^servicios/$', views.servicios, name="servicios"),
    url(r'^portafolio/$', views.portafolio, name="portafolio"),
    url(r'^contactenos/$', views.contact, name="contactenos"),
    url(r'^inicio/$', views.inicio, name="inicio"),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
]
```

Comment: What is your hosting provider and how have you configured the server? The "it worked" page is usually on `www.mydomain.com/`, so it looks like the admin prefix is causing you problems.

Comment: @Alasdair I'm working with A2 hosting, and I setup my application via CPanel (Following the given tutorial), there I was able to create my virtualenv with all the requierements my project needs, even if I leave the login form in blank and click log in It throws me 404